# Match text both inside and outside html tags, with grouping

Tags: regex

I'd like to process with regex the following string, such that I'd get groups of matches having and\or not-having html tags:

```
zero<pre>one</pre>two three<span>four</span>five
```

- I also care about the content of the html tag.

Expected result (I denote the group numbering with `x`, because I'm not sure what would be the result group number):

```
match 1: zero
match 2: <pre>one</pre>, group x: one -- and other groups having pre tags
match 3: two three
match 4: <span>four</span>, group x: four -- and other groups having span tags
match 5: five
```

What I tried ([live demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xfx09i/1)):

```
((<(.*?)>)?(.*?)(<\/(.*?)>))?
```

Or differently ([live demo](https://regex101.com/r/uDQdXk/1)):

```
(<(.*?)>)?(?:.?)
```

Both don't work.
I think I should just control for the beginning and ending (`zero` and `five` in the above example), but I can't get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would replace the `.*?` everywhere with what you are really looking for.

The regular expression could be this:

```
(?=.+)((<([^>]+)>)?([^<]+)?(<\/([^>]+)>)?)
```

- `(?=.+)` will make sure the match starts with something. All our capture groups are optional here, so to avoid an extra *null* match at the end we'll use this lookahead
- When finding the tagname: `[^>]+`
- When finding text in tags: `[^<]+`
- `([^<]+)?` makes text within spans optional

Regex101 playground:
https://regex101.com/r/1caMOA/2

Comment: Can we get rid of the trailing null match?

Comment: Yes you're right. I removed the `?` at the end, this seems to do it.

Comment: Hmm. It breaks in case there's an empty tag, like `<span></span>`.

Comment: Oh in that case it is `([^<]+)?` of course. In that case I would have a null match again at the end since all three capture groups are optional.

Comment: You mean inserting `(?=)` somewhere? I can't seem to make find where exactly

Comment: I believe I found it. Updating answer now.